# Iterate through collection and print Index and Item in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having problems with my razor view. I have the following:

```
public ICollection<Topic> Topics

public class Topic
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to iterate through the collection and print out the results like this:

```
    @foreach (int index in Enumerable.Range(0, Model.Topics.Count())){

        <div>@(index). Model.Topics[@(index)].Description"</div>
    }
```

The problem is that all I get is:

```
0. Model.Topics[0].Description"
1. Model.Topics[1].Description"
```

I tried all kinds of things but still can't get the description out.

What am I doing wrong :-(

Comment: why so afraid of `for` loops? sure, `foreach` is often clearer, but I wouldn't write off `for` completely.

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Topics)` is a lot clearer too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Topics)
{
    <div>@Model.Topics.IndexOf(item). @item.Description</div>
}
```

Comment: Something wrong as it says: 'Storage.Models.Topic' does not contain a definition for 'Topics' and no extension method 'Topics' accepting a first argument of type 'Storage.Models.Topic' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Rene, how about this `@item.model.Description`? I have updated my answer. It was a mistake on my part as I was calling the `.Select` already on the `Topics property of the model.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (Topic tp in Model.Topics){
    <div>@(i++).ToString() @tp.Description</div>
}
```

What your doing is trying to use the `foreach` like a for loop. (Possibly like a C++ iterator?) The foreach is however syntactic sugar that does all that work for you.

In C# foreach loops over typed collections. So if you have :

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
Person[] persons = //collection of persons
```

The loops would be:

```
foreach(int n in numbers) { /*n would be each of the numbers*/  }
foreach(Person p in persons) 
    {/* p here would refer to each person per iteration*/ }
```

Works for anything IEnumerable (which is IList, Arrays, Collections etc)

Comment: He wants to print the index as well.

Comment: @Darin aha! Did peer at the question a few times but didnt notice! Excellent catch and your answer is so elegant! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@foreach (int index in Enumerable.Range(0, Model.Topics.Count())){

        <div>@(index). @Model.Topics[index].Description</div>
}
```

Or even better:

```
@{ int i = 1; }
@foreach (var topic in Model.Topics){
    <div>@(i++). @topic.Description</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael, this one works although I kind of prefer the solution that Darin gave as it looks cool.

Comment: If you do this alot there is a even nicer solution by using templated delegates. Phil Haack writes about it here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/14/a-better-razor-foreach-loop.aspx