# Displaying one object value (from a collection) in a label

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC4. I could display records in a tabular format using `foreach`.

Now, I need to display the`Description` of (only) first `Topic` object in a label. I need to do it without a `foreach`. How can we do it?

**VIEW**

```
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.LabelDisplay

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


    foreach (var item in Model.Topics.Select((model, index) => new { index, model }))
    {
    <div>@(item.index) --- @item.model.Description---- @item.model.Code</div> <div></div>
    }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            LabelDisplay model = new LabelDisplay();

            Topic t = new Topic();
            t.Description = "Computer";
            t.Code=101;

            Topic t3 = new Topic();
            t3.Description = "Electrical";
            t3.Code = 102;


            model.Topics = new List<Topic>();
            model.Topics.Add(t);
            model.Topics.Add(t3);

            return View(model);
        }
```

**Model**

```
namespace MvcSampleApplication.Models
{
    public class LabelDisplay
    {
        public List<Topic> Topics;
    }

    public class Topic
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**REFERENCE**

1. [Iterate through collection and print Index and Item in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674621/iterating-through-a-collection-with-mvc3-and-razor)

Comment: don't do your LINQ in view. Create a view model for your view and send data in that

Comment: @Shyju: performing a LINQ *query* (something that will actually cause a database query to be issued) in view would be wrong, but LINQ, in general, is not necessarily "wrong" to have in your view. In particular, the OP here is following a common pattern to get a index value inside a foreach, which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to display theDescription of (only) first Topic object in a label

Unless I totally misunderstood you, selecting the first item (only) in your view would look something like:

```
@if (Model.Topics.Any())
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Topics.First().Description)
}
```

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that won't work using `LabelFor` -- you'll get a runtime error. However, the OP can use the `Model.Topics.First().Description` bit with just a static label tag easily enough.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Wow, actually ... this is a bit embarassing, you see it won't throw an exception, but it's actually adding a `label` element to the page ... Yeah, it's been a long day ...

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov The LableFor is not in your updated answer. Don't we need it?

Comment: @Lijo The `LabelFor` helper will generate an html element `<label for="Description">Description</label>` rather than just output the description itself. That said, it has an overload that accepts the text contents as a parameter. However an Html label element is usually used on forms that have corresponding textboxes/inputs for it. Not sure that is the case for you.

Comment: @Lijo This might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636502/why-use-label

Comment: @Lijo IMHO (and what I would do is simply use `@Html.DisplayFor`, I've edited the answer.